# How to put color on the image without affecting the transparent area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am wondering how to put color on the image without affecting the transparent area. I must say that I want to apply a gradient with a hard transition.

I tried to implement it through the svg, but there is a problem in the animation of the gradient.

I tried to make it through the mask, but it works correctly only in webkit.

There was an option to make a div with a gradient, and on top of it lay a picture with a background (I've seen on other sites), but my background does not allow to do it is not noticeable to the eye.

Default picture:

[image]

It should be:

[image]

It should be possible to animate:

[image]

Thanks for answers! :)

Comment: Do you have any code that we can see?

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson I don't know what code I could show you.

Comment: *Maybe* something with CSS Filters but it won't be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not perfect, but can be a beginning:

```css
.base {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sklUO.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;  
  animation: move 12s infinite linear;
}

.t1 {
  top: 0px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  filter: sepia(100%) saturate(200) hue-rotate(40deg);
}
.t2 {
  top: 200px;
  background-position: 0px -200px;
  filter: sepia(100%) saturate(200) hue-rotate(130deg);
  animation-delay: -3s;
}
.t3 {
  top: 400px;
  background-position: 0px -400px;
  filter: sepia(100%) saturate(200) hue-rotate(220deg);
  animation-delay: -6s;
}
.t4 {
  top: 600px;
  background-position: 0px -600px;
  filter: sepia(100%) saturate(200) hue-rotate(310deg);
  animation-delay: -9s;
}


@keyframes move {
  from {
  top: -200px;
  background-position: 0px 200px;

  }
  to {
  top: 600px;
  background-position: 0px -600px;

  }
}




body {
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="test t1"></div>
<div class="test t2"></div>
<div class="test t3"></div>
<div class="test t4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I understand it, I will only use filters. I just have to be not only the rgb, and absolutely any color, but the idea is interesting.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that it is possible to make filters! It is a pity that does not work in IE, but I will require at the entrance to the site to download a normal browser to use site :D

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, maybe you should create a png where the shape of the image is cut out. so your image will be at the bottom, then in divs you can have your coloured divs with little bit of opacity & as a topmost later, you keep the new png ( the inverted version ) as the top most layer. This might work.

Let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I can not do that with cut out png where transparent area = background and default image = transparent area, because my background is dynamic.
If it with 1% opacity, we can be seen gradient at the bottom div.
If I do not understand you, please give an example on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What did you mean by dynamic background? the colors are dynamic / the image itself is dynamic?

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/hjvxcu92/
First there was a picture where background-size: cover. Return to this option will fits me if it will work with gradient image.